# Some Applications don't open in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64 bit)

Tags: installation

Following applications those installed doesn't open in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system.

1. CreBS ( installed with : sudo add-apt-repository ppa:crebs/ppa ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install crebs )
2. Ubuntu TV -Unity 2d ( installed with : sudo apt-get -y build-dep unity-2d ; sudo add-apt-repository ppa:u2t/bleedingedge ; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install unity-2d-shell)
3. Video 4 linux ( installed with : sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libv4l/ppa ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install gtk-v4l )
4. FFMPEG ( installed with : Adding followings to "/ect/apt/sources.list"....; deb http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse ; deb-src """"" precise multiverse ; deb """"" precise-updates multiverse ; deb-src """"" precise-updates multiverse : ....Then Running:   sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev )
5. WebCamStudio ( installed with : sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/multimedia ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install webcamstudio )

I installed Ubuntu with downloaded "Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS amd64.iso" file from www.ubuntu.com. Updates have done with update Manager also. I am the administrator and only user. I installed above packages with root prompt "#"( running "$ sudo su").

This is a "Toshiba Satellite c650" Laptop with "Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz × 4 " , 500 GB hard disk , 2 GB RAM , and "Intel® Ironlake Mobile" graphics. This is the only operating system in the computer.

I am doing Videography and don't know much about computing. I need expert help !.

Comment: You could have installed ffmpeg from the Ubuntu Software Center, and while you're at it there's a graphical interface for running ffmpeg outside of the terminal called called WinFF that you can also install from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Thanks Karel... So I installed WinFF. But the screen is derrerent from this.                 http://www.google.lk/imgres?q=screenshot+of+FFMPEG&sa=X&biw=1301&bih=654&tbm=isch&tbnid=2NU7X6uL3P-V_M:&imgrefurl=http://www.delphiffmpeg.com/screenshot/&docid=a4q7J9km7xLnmM&imgurl=http://www.delphiffmpeg.com/screenshots/delphi-ffmpeg-video-converter-option.png&w=693&h=607&ei=6UuwUaX8AcyHrAfhoICICg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:2,s:0,i:85&iact=rc&dur=6716&page=1&tbnh=182&tbnw=208&start=0&ndsp=16&tx=128&ty=91

Comment: That's OK, WinFF should look like [this](https://debianhelp.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/screenshot-from-2012-04-12-190555.png?w=625).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try another video application on your list: CreBS. Open the terminal and type: `crebs`. If CreBS opens with this command, you will want to add it to the Dash so that you can open Video 4 Linux by searching for it in the Dash and then clicking on its icon.

If you want to be able to see CreBS in the Unity Dash you should create a .desktop file using Gedit. Open Gedit and type:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=CreBS
Comment=Create Background Slideshow
TryExec=path-to-CreBS-application
Exec=path-to-CreBS-application %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=path-to-CreBS-icon
```

Save this file with the name CreBS.desktop to the `~/.local/share/applications` folder. Replace *path-to-CreBS-application* and *path-to-CreBS-icon* with the paths from your system.

Comment: # gtk-v4l  Not opens it. Previously, because it not opens, I uninstalled gtk-v4l and reinstalled the software centre application "video 4 Linux control panel". Here it is mentioned as v4l2. Is "video 4 Linux control panel" defferent from "video 4 linux" ?.

Comment: You're on the right track. You might need to install some other v4l2 packages though from this [list of v4l2 packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=v4l2&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: Thanks. I will return with installed them. The thing I need to get my video 8 analog camera(av) to computer(DV) via USB TV-tuner (gadmei utv382e). This is the device i used before in windows. But gadmei.com has not given a driver for linux. In windows, i could open this via VLC player without the driver given by Gadmei. But here in Ubuntu, cannot open it with VLC. I thought there might have a solution with Video 4 Linux. Is it correct ?. Is there any other method or do I need to move for a new expensive camera. ?

Comment: I'm not allowed to have more than 8 or maybe 10 comments on a single answer and no long comments, but that's OK, I'll look into it, and write a long answer and upload it to Ubuntu Pastebin, and you can download it from there. I'll add the link(s) to whatever file(s) I upload to Ubuntu Pastebin to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Karel... For your great help. I installed all the v4l and v4l2 packages from your link. After uninstall gtk-v4l, now unable to reinstall it. It says "unable to locate gtk-v4l".I could open CreBS by Alt + F2 and searching it. Thanks for your help. I seek someone others help to resolve remaining two problems with Ubuntu TV and WebCamStudio.